# Printing Values Regarding Objects in a Class (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I have written this code to organize student's grades. How can I receive students scores via user input (using an indefinite number in python) and output the student with the highest average using the included "top" class object?

I am a beginner when it comes to coding in python, pls help me solve this problem.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, n, g):
        self.name = n
        self.gender = g
        self.grades = []

    def add(self,grade):
        #do something.
        self.grades.append(grade)

    def avg(self):
        #do something.
        #return avg_grade
        return 0

    def fcount(self):
        #do something.
        #return fail_count
        return 0

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name:%s Avg:%.2f Subject(s) less than 60:%d" % (self.name, self.avg(), self.fcount())

    @classmethod
    def top(cls, *students):
        tops = students[0]
        for s in students:
            print(s.grades)
        return tops

s1 = Student("Tom","M")
s2 = Student("Jane","F")
s3 = Student("John","M")
s4 = Student("Ann","F")
s5 = Student("Peter","M")
s1.add(80)
s1.add(90)
s1.add(55)
s1.add(77)
s1.add(40)
s2.add(58)
s2.add(87)
s3.add(100)
s3.add(80)
s4.add(40)
s4.add(55)
s5.add(60)
s5.add(60)

print(str(s1))
print(str(s2))
print(str(s3))
print(str(s4))
print(str(s5))
tops = Student.top(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5)
print("Student w/ Highest Score:{} ; Average Score: {}".format(tops.name, tops.avg()))
```

Output:

```
Name:Tom Avg:0.00 Subject(s) less than 60:0
Name:Jane Avg:0.00 Subject(s) less than 60:0
Name:John Avg:0.00 Subject(s) less than 60:0
Name:Ann Avg:0.00 Subject(s) less than 60:0
Name:Peter Avg:0.00 Subject(s) less than 60:0
[80, 90, 55, 77, 40]
[58, 87]
[100, 80]
[40, 55]
[60, 60]
Student w/ Highest Score:Tom ; Average Score:0
```

Comment: Is `top` part of the class?

Comment: Yes, top is an object of the class

Comment: I have provided a solution

Answer (score 0):

Change the `avg` method to this:

```
@property
def avg(self):
  return sum(self.grades) / float(len(self.grades))
```

`@property` is a decorator and a syntactic sugar to make this method a "getter". Or if you wish, it can also be thought of as a "computed property". It is not important for solving your problem but is a nice way of structuring your class.

You don't need the `top` to be a class method. Since you are passing all the objects into it, including "itself" then you can make this method a main function. Alternatively, you could also create another class called, say `Classroom` that has a property `students` which will be all the `Student` objects. Then you could also have a class method there called `top_student`. But for now, the following function could also be a main function:

```
def top(*students):
    top_student = students[0]

    for student in students:
        if student.avg > top_student.avg:
          top_student = student

    return top_student
```

**Plugging this to your code:**

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, n, g):
        self.name = n
        self.gender = g
        self.grades = []

    def add(self,grade):
        #do something.
        self.grades.append(grade)

    @property
    def avg(self):
        return 0 if len(self.grades) == 0 else sum(self.grades) / float(len(self.grades))

    def fcount(self):
        #do something.
        #return fail_count
        return 0

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: {}, Avg: {:2}".format(self.name, self.avg)

class Classroom:
    def __init__(self, *students):
        self.students = students

    def input_grades_per_student(self):
        for student in self.students:
            while True:
                grade = input("Enter {}'s grade (or leave empty to continue to the next student): ".format(student.name))
                if len(grade) == 0:
                    print()
                    break

                try:
                   grade = float(grade)
                   student.add(grade)
                except ValueError:
                   print("That's not a number.")

    @property
    def top_student(self):
        top_student = self.students[0]

        for student in self.students:
            if student.avg > top_student.avg:
                top_student = student

        return top_student

s1 = Student("Tom","M")
s2 = Student("Jane","F")
s3 = Student("John","M")
s4 = Student("Ann","F")
s5 = Student("Peter","M")

classroom = Classroom(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5)
classroom.input_grades_per_student()
print("Student with highest score:{} ; Average score: {}".format(classroom.top_student.name, classroom.top_student.avg))
```

Here I also created a `Classroom` class to make things easier to read.

**Output:**

```
Enter Tom's grade (or leave empty to continue to the next student): 15
Enter Tom's grade (or leave empty to continue to the next student): 20
Enter Tom's grade (or leave empty to continue to the next student): 

Enter Jane's grade (or leave empty to continue to the next student): 12
Enter Jane's grade (or leave empty to continue to the next student): 13
Enter Jane's grade (or leave empty to continue to the next student): 

Enter John's grade (or leave empty to continue to the next student): 16
Enter John's grade (or leave empty to continue to the next student): 

Enter Ann's grade (or leave empty to continue to the next student): 17
Enter Ann's grade (or leave empty to continue to the next student): 

Enter Peter's grade (or leave empty to continue to the next student): 18
Enter Peter's grade (or leave empty to continue to the next student): 

Student with highest score:Peter ; Average score: 18.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `scan_grades`, `avg` and `top` methods:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, n, g):
        self.name = n
        self.gender = g
        self.grades = []

    def scan_grades(self):
        subject_count = input('Enter number of subjects: ')
        for i in range(subject_count):
            score = float(input('Enter score: ')
            self.add(score)

    def add(self,grade):
        #do something.
        self.grades.append(grade)

    def avg(self):
        return sum(self.grades) / len(self.graders)

    def fcount(self):
        #do something.
        #return fail_count
        return 0

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name:%s Avg:%.2f Subject(s) less than 60:%d" % (self.name, self.avg(), self.fcount())

    @classmethod
    def top(cls, *students):
        top_student = max(students, key = lambda std: std.avg())
        return top_student
```

- You can scan the grades of a student using `scan_grades` method.
- The `top` method gets the student with max average. It uses

  1. `max`([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#max))
  2. `lambda`([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions))